# How to put pictures in running text as if they were text?

Tags: text-wrap

Some tutorial books have text lines containing graphics like these:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It'd be a lot nicer to build an OpenType-SVG font, but there doesn't seem to be any intuitive workable tool for that yet. Thus I'd like to know how to put graphics (especially colored graphics) into running text like the above examples, as if the graphics were text themselves, so that the graphics are aligned perfectly and consistently on text lines. **Not just symbols already built in fonts, but actual graphics (rastor, vector, etc., especially colored ones)** Ideally using Adobe apps.

Comment: Uhm.. use Font Awesome or similar icon-only fonts?

Comment: Normal fonts (icon-only and whatnot) only appear black and white.

Comment: Icon fonts work just like any font so you insert icons and change the color as you would for a normal character.

Comment: @Lucian Unless the font is already colored, inserting black and white characters of any sorts and coloring them every single time is not ideal for working on large-scale works. Look, I'm not that clueless, okay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Adobe InDesign. Place the image and anchor it to the text where it belongs.

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html

If trying for web just create a custom CSS class for yourself.

Photoshop and Illustrator don't really have features for this. You can wrap text around objects in both but they won't automatically adjust with the text.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://www.fontself.com

Fontself is a commercial add-on to **create fonts from vector or raster artwork** within Photoshop and Illustrator:

- In Photoshop you can export OpenType-SVG color bitmap fonts from any image layer.
- In Illustrator you will soon be able to export color vector fonts from multicolored shapes.

Check the PS demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7JUBCdgi0w

And the great news for AI users: https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/color-fonts-coming-to-illustrator-cc/

Answer (score 1):

InDesign allows you to paste RGB images from your Pasteboard into the Text Box. I do this all the time.

1. Create a text box,
2. start typing,
3. leave the cursor at the last character,
4. go to Photoshop and copy/paste a flatten RGB (not
   transparent layer)
5. go back to your cursor in InDesign and paste.

After the image is pasted, you can also select the image's corner anchors and resize (bonus!)

Warning: if your file is going to press, be aware that your image was placed as a screen resolution BMP format.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at https://www.colorfonts.wtf/

You can use Fontself which is addon to Photoshop and Illustrator.

https://www.fontself.com/

It uses OpenType-SVG like you wanted. That should solve your problem. Its $49.